# How to verify that field is greater than only if check on a specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, button

Sorry for my dummie question but I am not familiar with JQuery. I want to check that a field value is greater than other field value only when the user click on a specific button. I have two buttons on my form for submit values with a different button value.
This is the JavaScript code I don't know how to write it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // If click on DKV button, check thaht field prix_total > litrage
    // else if click on GR, do not check that prix_total > litrage
    $("#creer_carburant_DKV").click(function(){
        var price = $("#prix_total").val();
      var liter = $("#litrage").val();
        if (price > liter){
        // send the form
      }else{
        alert("The price must be greater than liter");
      }

     $("#creer_carburant_GR").click(function(){
        // If prix_total is not set, define to 0
    });
```

This is a working example on JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/04mpbfcx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop submitting the form when something goes wrong. Use another event instead of clicking the button.
Like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#creer_carburant_DKV").click(function(){
        var price = $("#prix_total").val();
        var liter = $("#litrage").val();
        if (Number(price) > Number(liter)){
            // send the form
        }else{
            alert("The price must be greater than liter");
            event.preventDefault(); // This causes the submit event to be canceled
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is comparing two strings rather than numbers. You can just convert price and liter to numbers and you should be fine.

```
if (Number(price) > Number(liter)) {
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanwadd/qbpzsn9d/)

Comment: Thank for your answer but the form is sent even if I cast to Number.